# MySQL: Procedure for mysql certification

Tags: mysql

I have keen interest in database and since start of my career I worked only in MySQL. But, I have not any professional certification related with MySQL. I have below concerns for certification:

- Any minimum eligibility like education or experience
- What are the similarities and differences between MySQL certification and MySQL DBA certification?
- What is the procedure for registration and appearing in the exam?
- What will be the total cost in India?
- How much beneficial it would be in my career?
- Recommend few good tutorials or documentations or Books for this certification?

Your suggestion would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL certification, exam, course & cost details can all be found on the Oracle Education site here (Indian site linked to):

https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=458&get_params=p_track_id:MYSQLDBA56OCP

The certification process is simple enough to become a MySQL Certified Associate or Professional.  You just need to pass the relevant exams (e.g. for Oracle Certified Professional, MySQL 5.6 Database Administrator, you have to pass 1Z0-883 / MySQL 5.6 Database Administrator).

That's it.

For the Expert certification status things are a bit more complex, but check out the Oracle Education site linked above.

The cost is high if you do the courses and the exams.  If you're confident in your abilities and have lots of experience, you can do the exams without having done the courses, but in my experience, doing the course is a good grounding and they will cover everything that the exam requires.

How beneficial?  Well that depends on the job market, employer's requirements and your other skills.  Obviously a certification separates you from people who don't have one, but that's all you can realistically say.  There will be non-certified people with more experience than you.

Comment: Is "MySQL certified professional" different than "
MySQL Certified DBA"?

Comment: Oracle provide 3 levels of certification for MySQL: Associate, Professional and Expert.  Personally, I would avoid associate as a starting point because it is very basic.  However, having said that you may find it useful.  There are 2 "branches" of MySQL Professional Certifications: DBA and Developer.  Both have different focusses but with some similar core subjects.  See https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=39 for a list of available certifications.

Comment: See this page for some more information about different "levels" of certification: https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=146